# Здраствуйте.Помогите решит проблему с вывидением в екран картины некоторые информатции(В localStorage сохроняетса но не выводитса)

Tags: javascript, html

```
let currentComputerId = document.getElementById("currentId");
let currentSeller = localStorage.getItem("logged-in-username");
let localStorageItem = localStorage.getItem("Computer");
let categoriesString = localStorage.getItem("categories")
let Computers = [];
let categories=[];


let username = localStorage.getItem("logged-in-username")

if (localStorageItem == null) {
    Computers= [];
} else {
  Computers = JSON.parse(localStorageItem);
}

function changeToIndexpage() {
    window.location.href = "Esas Sehife.html";
}





function editComputerVallues(id) {
    let Computer = Computers[id];
    currentId.innerText = id;
    let name = document.getElementById("name2");
    let videocart=document.getElementById("videocart2")
    let category = document.getElementById("category2");
    let PCcategory = document.getElementById("PCcategory2");
    let price = document.getElementById("price2");
    let type = document.getElementById("type2");
    let isnew = document.getElementById("isnew2");
    let image = document.getElementById("image2");
    let ram = document.getElementById("ram2");
    let rom = document.getElementById("rom2");
    let pross= document.getElementById("pross2");

    name.value = Computer.name;
    category.value = Computer.category;
    price.value = Computer.price;
    type.value = Computer.type;
    isnew.value = Computer.isnew;
    image.value = Computer.image;
    videocart.value=Computer.videocart;
    ram.value = Computer.ram;
    rom.value = Computer.rom;
    pross.value=Computer.pross;
    PCcategory.value=Computer.PCcategory;

  }

function editComputer(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let id = currentId.innerText;

  let name = document.getElementById("name2").value;
  let category = document.getElementById("category2").value;
  let price = document.getElementById("price2").value;
  let type = document.getElementById("type2").value;
  let isnew = document.getElementById("isnew2").value;
  let image = document.getElementById("image2").value;
  let ram = document.getElementById("ram2").value;
  let rom = document.getElementById("rom2").value;
  let pross= document.getElementById("pross2").value;
  let videocart= document.getElementById("videocart2").value;
  let PCcategory = document.getElementById("PCcategory2").value;

  Computers[id].name = name;
  Computers[id].category = category;
  Computers[id].price = price;
  Computers[id].type = type;
  Computers[id].isnew = isnew;
  Computers[id].image = image;
  Computers[id].videocart = videocart;
  Computers[id].pross = pross;
  Computers[id].rom = ram;
  Computers[id].rom = rom;
  Computers[id].rom = PCcategory;


  localStorage.setItem("Computers", JSON.stringify(Computers));
  window.location.reload();

}

function loadComputer() {
  let table = document.getElementById("customtableContent");
  for (let i = 0; i < Computers.length; i++) {
      let Computer = Computers[i];
      if (Computer.seller = currentSeller) {


          let id = Computer.id;
          let name = Computer.category + Computer.name;
          let image = Computer.image;
          let price = Computer.price;

          let tr = document.createElement("tr");

          let idtd = document.createElement("td");
          let nametd = document.createElement("td");
          let imagetd = document.createElement("td");
          let pricetd = document.createElement("td");
          let actiontd = document.createElement("td");

          idtd.innerText = id;
          nametd.innerText = name;
          let imageElement = document.createElement("img");
          imageElement.style.width = "100px"
          imageElement.src = image;
          imagetd.appendChild(imageElement);
          pricetd.innerText = price;


          let editButon = document.createElement("button");
          editButon.innerText = "Redakt et";
          editButon.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-info text-white");
          editButon.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "modal");
          editButon.setAttribute("data-bs-target", "#modal2");
          editButon.setAttribute("onclick", "editComputerVallues(" + id + ")");

          let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
          deleteButton.innerText = "Sil";
          deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-danger");
          deleteButton.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteComputer(" + id + ")");
          actiontd.appendChild(editButon);

          actiontd.appendChild(deleteButton);






          tr.appendChild(idtd);
          tr.appendChild(nametd);
          tr.appendChild(imagetd);
          tr.appendChild(pricetd);
          tr.appendChild(actiontd)


          table.appendChild(tr);
      }
  }

}

function deleteComputer(id) {

  for (let i = 0; i < Computers.length; i++) {
      let Computer = Computers[i];
      if (Computer.id == id) {
        Computers.splice(Computers[i], 1);
          localStorage.setItem("Computers", JSON.stringify(Computers))
          window.location.reload();
      }
  }
}



function addComputer(event) {
  event.preventDefault();


  let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  let category = document.getElementById("category").value;
  let price = document.getElementById("price").value;
  let type = document.getElementById("type").value;
  let isnew = document.getElementById("isnew").value;
  let image = document.getElementById("image").value;
  let ram = document.getElementById("ram").value;
  let rom = document.getElementById("rom").value;
  let PCcategory=document.getElementById("PCcategory").value;
  let videocart=document.getElementById("videocart").value;
  let pross=document.getElementById("pross").value;

  let Computer = {};
  Computer.id = Computers.length;
  Computer.name = name;
  Computer.category = category;
  Computer.price = price;
  Computer.isnew = isnew;
  Computer.image = image;
  Computer.ram = ram;
  Computer.rom = rom;
  Computer.type = type;
  Computer.username = username;
  Computer.PCcategory = PCcategory;
  Computer.videocart=videocart;
  Computer.pross=pross;

  Computers.push(Computer);

  localStorage.setItem("Computers", JSON.stringify(Computers));

  window.location.reload();
}

loadComputer();
```

Comment: Вы сохраняете "Computer**s**" а пытаетесь прочитать "Computer". Если у вас пробелема с другим хранилищем, укажите явно его имя

Comment: Спасибо огромное.Реално помогли :)